# how can I hide my IP Address?

Tags: web, ip

Guys I really want to know how to hide my IP Address. And know why is it necessary to hide it?
I tried using anonymox, but I want to hide it without using any third party software.

Comment: Answer to your off-topic question: It depends on which OS.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 pro. so can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the methods listed here : https://pc4u.org/windows-10-how-to-connect-to-a-free-vpn-without-going-through-third-party-software/ if you don't want to use a third party software to hide your IP Address. You need to setup a VPN in your computer to achieve that. This will tunnel your network connection.

Source: pc4u.org

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this without 3rd party software would be to use an online proxy and configure your browser to use said proxy. This will only change your IP as it appears to sites you visit through the browser and not other services you may be using on your computer.

The "best" way to "hide" or change your IP is to use a VPN (which you'll need software for). You can purchase a VPN service from one of Many providers. Some of the providers have their own apps that you can use, or, you can manually configure your own OpenVPN client. There are also many great scripts out there, AWS one-click servers, and cheap VPS providers that make it easier than ever to create your own VPN server. This might be over the "average" users head though...

The benefit of using a VPN is that it not only changes your IP, also encrypt your traffic.

It should be noted that VPN's are not 100% fool-proof. If not configured properly, you will expose your real IP. In addition, many VPN providers are not reputable.

The best recommendation I can make on this and every other topic on online privacy is this site here:

https://privacytools.io

This is (IMO) the best, most comprehensive source of information about protecting your privacy online. They will guide you in the right direction regarding VPN's, proxies, securing your browser, and much, much more. Check it out. Seriously...

OpenVPN has builds for all operating systems. https://openvpn.net
Like i said though, you'll have to purchase access (or if you're brave, find a free 'solution') from a provider and then configure OpenVPN to use your purchased credentials. This is usually about 5$ a month (for the solid / no logs / unlimited bandwidth ones ). There are many, many posts about setting up OpenVPN here on stackoverflow.

Finally, as far as the proxies go, again, you can purchase access to some of the reputable ones or search for a free one - though, in my experience the free proxies are very touch and go.

Comment: Thanks mate, Godspeed